# "See your profile" link doesn't go to profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, top-bar, achievements-dialog

In my "achievements" menu on the top bar, I was told that I earned a badge for a question, and to see my profile.

[image: I'm awesome, right?]

Anyway, the link took me to the post in question, not to my profile.  Maybe we should have the post title link to the post and "your profile" link to the profile?

Comment: It seems to depend on the type of badge. A badge linked to a post (question/answer) will link to that post; a badge like *Civic Duty* (gained by voting 300 times) will link to your profile.

Comment: @Stijn: Makes sense, but if it's telling me to "see my profile", and doesn't link me there, it can be confusing.

Comment: Yeah, it is a wording bug. I would tag it as such

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're going to fix this after some re-factoring of the inbox and notifications code.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Cool :-D

Answer (score 0):

These achievement notifications no longer say "see your profile" if the notification links to a question page.